# Blank Page in react I have searched stackovwerflow but found nothing

Tags: reactjs

**can anyone help me react is giving blank page when I render feed before Router its showing feed but inside router no component is working it was working fine but suddenly some issue arised and i guess ot is due to route i tried to downgrade react-router-dom it didnt work**
import React from "react";

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import "./App.css";

import Feed from "./Components/Feed"; 
import {AuthProvider} from "./AuthProvider"
function App() {
  return (
  <>
   {/* <Feed /> */}
  <Router>
    <AuthProvider>
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Feed />}></Route>
      </Routes>
    </AuthProvider>
  </Router>
</>
  );
}
```

export default App;
package.json:
{
"name": "instagram-clone",
"version": "0.1.0",
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
"@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
"@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.11",
"@mui/material": "^5.11.15",
"@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
"@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
"@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
"firebase": "^9.8.0",
"firebase-tools": "^11.25.1",
"pure-react-carousel": "^1.30.1",
"react": "^18.2.0",
"react-dom": "^18.2.0",
"react-router-dom": "^6.10.0",
"react-scripts": "5.0.1",
"web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
},
"scripts": {
"start": "react-scripts start",
"build": "react-scripts build",
"test": "react-scripts test",
"eject": "react-scripts eject"
},
"eslintConfig": {
"extends": [
"react-app",
"react-app/jest"
]
},
"browserslist": {
"production": [
">0.2%",
"not dead",
"not op_mini all"
],
"development": [
"last 1 chrome version",
"last 1 firefox version",
"last 1 safari version"
]
}
}

Comment: Self close the `Route` component `<Route path="/" element={<Feed/>} />`?

Comment: Still not working any idea